# iPhone OpenGL texture not completely transparent

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, transparent

I tried to paint a transparent texture over a sphere, but the transparent areas are not completely transparent. A vivid shade of gray remains. I tried to load a Photoshop generated PNG then paint it on sphere using the code below:

My code to load textures:

```
- (void) loadPNGTexture: (int)index Name: (NSString*) name{
    CGImageRef imageRef = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",name]].CGImage;

    GLsizei width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    GLsizei height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);
    GLubyte * data = malloc(width * 4 * height);
    if (!data)
        NSLog(@"error allocating memory for texture loading!");
    else {
        NSLog(@"Memory allocated for %@", name);
    }

    NSLog(@"Width : %d, Height :%d",width,height);
    CGContextRef cg_context = CGBitmapContextCreate(data, width, height, 8, 4 * width, CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);//kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(cg_context, 0, height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(cg_context, 1, -1);
    CGContextDrawImage(cg_context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), imageRef);
    CGContextRelease(cg_context);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(cg_context, kCGBlendModeCopy); //kCGBlendModeCopy);

    glGenTextures(2, m_texture[index]);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture[index][0]);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    free(data);
}
```

Drawing clouds:

```
glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(0, 0, 3   );
glScalef(3.1, 3.1, 3.1);
glRotatef(-1, 0, 0, 1);
glRotatef(90, -1, 0, 0);
glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

//Load Texture for left side of globe
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_texture[CLOUD_TEXTURE][0]);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(TexturedVertexData3D), &VertexData[0].vertex);
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(TexturedVertexData3D), &VertexData[0].normal);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(TexturedVertexData3D), &VertexData[0].texCoord);
// draw the sphere
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_COPY);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 11520);


glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: Show us the (relevant section of) code. Ideally something minimal we could try ourselves. And are you sure the texture has transparency/an alpha channel?

Comment: This feels like a silly question: if the result were completely transparent wouldn't it be invisible?

Comment: Have you activate `glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)`? I believe this can affect or add "material" shading, see `glMaterial(…)`

Comment: @MrMusic: No it wouldn't, because there is another sphere within this sphere.

Comment: @epatel please describe more.

Comment: @Bart: I used Photoshop to create 32bit PNG, not enough?

Comment: Show us relevant code, perhaps show us a screenshot of the result you get and make sure your PNG is truly properly transparent in those areas you wish it to be.

Comment: @Bart please check code in edited question

Comment: @AVEbrahimi Given your comment am I to assume my answer below solved your problem?

Comment: Yes, but I have another question:

I tried to write text using open-gl, but when I write second letter it clips the first letter ( the transparent area of second clips the first letter)

Comment: That is a different question and should not be asked here. Create a new question for it and perhaps mark this one as answered/solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This first thing that stands out in your code is the line:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_COPY);
```

The second argument ([`GL_COPY`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glLogicOp.xml)), is not [a valid argument](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBlendFunc.xml) for `glBlendFunc`.
You might want to change that to something along the lines of

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```